# Помощь с алгоритмом рекурсии

Tags: java

Есть алгоритм рекурсии:

```
алг Процедура1(арг цел n)
нач
  если n > 0
    то
      вывод n
      Процедура1(n – 1)
  все
кон
```

Вот реализация:

```
static class recurs {
        int proc1(int n) {
            if (n > 0) {
                return n;                          //Если "вывод n" это return,
                new recurs().proc1(n - 1);          //как запустить Процедуру1 без return?
            }
            return n;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Вывод `n`" - это не `return`, а `System.out.println()`(в общем случае - вывод пользователю значение переменной `n` в данный момент), если работаете с консолью. Второй `return` удалите - метод не должен ничего возвращать. Также он должен быть статическим - результат выполнения не зависит от переменных данного объекта `recurs`.
Итого:

```
public static void proc1(int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        System.out.println(n);
        proc1(n - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Что-то у меня вообще ничего не выводит.
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        recurs f = new recurs();}

Comment: @Eugene Так вы должны вызывать метод класса - если `main` в `recurs`, то достаточно написать `proc1(number);`.

Comment: Чего я не понимаю? 
main является методом более верхнего класса, в который вложен и recurs. Вызов proc1 в main`e происходит как у вас в комментарии.

Comment: @Eugene Тогда `recurs.proc1(number)`